# Is it possible to open a local native Application like Terminal.app from a button in Chrome browser

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I know this sounds crazy... but I really hope to have something like this...

Click on a button in a page, like:

`localhost:8080/index`

And there is a button in it. When I click that button, it runs a local application. In this case I hope it can get some extra information from the button, like:

```
<button id="script1.sh">Run</button>
<script>
$("button").click(function(){
  var scriptName = $(this).attr("id");
  OpenTermninalWithScript(scriptName);
});
</script>
```

I am using Macintosh / Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

as you are on `localhost:8080/index` I assure you can open it from the **backend** part (frontend API is not yet evolved to have security permission which allow that in a safe manner)

To do so, your frontend script would create an ajax call to the backend at a specific url you choose asking the backend to proceed. You could start a child process in a terminal (you could do anything you want that is already possible via command line interface (CLI) or just use the default `open` to simplify

here is a nodejs / express example but it's possible with java, php python and manymore

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var app = require('express')();

app.get('/path/to/trigger/comand', function(req, res){
    spawn('open', ['http://google.com']);
    res.end('ok');
});

// [...]
```

open take a ressource to open, you may put here any kind of ressource your OS will open with it's default behaviour

Comment: thanks, what if I want to open a script with Terminal? Your example works well and the Chrome Browser opened google.com successfully but how about opening a given script in Terminal.app?

Comment: here is a good example of running script http://jaketrent.com/post/run-shell-script-nodejs/ then throught script you might do anything, like running `gnome-terminal` or `iterm`